# Pass a variable to a different method?

Tags: java, android, methods, android-spinner

hello I am making a bmi calculator i want it to work based on 3 variables, weight height and gender.
The gender in on a spinner which lets the user choose:

```
final Spinner spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity(),R.array.gender, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

The problem is the spinner uses a whole new method for it to work:

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      String gendertext = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), gendertext,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

i want to take that variable `gendertext` and use it on this part of code which is inside the `onCreateView`

```
        edit_height = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_height);
        edit_weight = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_weight);
        button_calculate_bmi = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_calculate_bmi);
        text_results = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_results);

        button_calculate_bmi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String results = "Results:";
                float height = 0;
                float weight = 0;
                try {
                    height = Float.parseFloat(edit_height.getText().toString());
                    weight = Float.parseFloat(edit_weight.getText().toString());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Context context = getActivity();
                    CharSequence text = "You forgot to enter something";
                            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }

                height = height/100;
                float bmi = weight / (height * height);






                text_results.setText(results+bmi);
            }
        });




        return view;
    }
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: Declare gendertext out of onItemSelected function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the `genderText` variable outside of all methods in the Activity and initialize it to the first item in your R.array.gender. When the value in spinner is changed, `onItemSelected` is called and you get the updated value which you can set to the variable `genderText`.

Then in the button `OnClickListener` you can use the `genderText` variable.

Comment: Thank you!! I cant believe it was that easy!